# Updated linked files not connecting with web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, xampp

In the head of my web page html document I have linked CSS and JavaScript files for the functionality and aesthetics of my page. They seemed to work fine, until I updated a JS file and it did not affect my page. Out of frustration, I eventually just added the script  to the bottom of the page as part of script tags and forgot about it. However, when I wanted to update some CSS files, the same thing happened.

I am using xampp and Sublime text 3 as text editor. I have triple checked the file locations and directories and they all match up. I cant think of any other issue that could cause this. Does anybody have any ideas? At the bottom I have attached an example of the head tags.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" >
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/page_layout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/top_nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/buttons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/side_nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/modal.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../java_script/top_nav.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you share your directory structure, i think there is some path issues

Comment: @SuperUser In what format please?

Comment: This will probably be an issue with the directory i.e. ../ part of your href/src

Comment: @billy.farroll I totally agree, the problem is it worked yesterday, and I have changed nothing. Now it's not linking the pages? And the pages still work as if they are linked, until you update the linked page...

Comment: Try inspecting the page and seeing if the scripts are connected (Resources tab). It might also be something within the files, e.g. you don't actually call a function

Comment: Ah right, have you changed anything in the folder you're calling them from? like removed or edited files? Or, have you tried relinking them back into the site?

Comment: @billy.farroll I am telling you, it's the weirdest thing... I just deleted the tags and it reflected in the page, re-added them and they are back to their old state. But any new updates to the css files are not reflected... So I have confirmed that the pages are linked.

Comment: @Mariska you can share image as well

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with Sublime Text 3, not any directory issues. Somehow it does not update and link files as it should. Once I close and reopen ST3, the changes show. I am considering using another text editor if this issue continues.